# How I can store the {{$time stamp}} variable in global varibale

Tags: variables, postman

On the end point I need to generate a number (for phone number) Thats why I used `{{$timestamp}}` in environment variable.

Is there any way I can store that same Timestamp in global varibale?

Answer (score 0):

you can use postman.setGlobalVariable() function to set the global variable and postman.getGlobalVariable() function to retrieve the value.

In your case, it should be:
postman.setGlobalVariable("timeStamp", [value]);

postman.getGlobalVariable("timeStamp");
or simply {{timeStamp}}